# How does an IR camera determine the temperature?

Tags: thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation, photometry

The IR cameras detect light in the IR where low temperature bodies (-20 - 40 deg) have their peaks of the black body radiance.

How the detectors associate temperature to intensity measurement on a pixel?

What is the difficulty to use regular CCD sensitive to the visible spectrum ?

Comment: IR cameras require calibration for different materials.

Answer (score 1):

Many materials are not perfect/ideal black body radiators.  When using an IR camera use the information provided or google to find the calibration factor for the material under observation. The sensor pixels (called a micro bolometer) produces a voltage proportional to the number of IR photons emitted from the material.  Another calibration method is to heat the material and check it with a thermometer and correct readings of the camera with a factor.  Distance to object is important as air absorbs some IR photons.  The visible spectrum photons do not depend/emit so much on temperature,  CCD not ideal.